# Weird Error: Abort trap while handling character array in C

Tags: c, string, off-by-one

I want to store the binary value of each character in a string and store it in an array. But when i start messing around with functions like `memset`, i have no control over the debugging.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char str[8];
char *ptr = "Hello";
int i;

for(; *ptr != 0; ++ptr)
{
    printf("%c => ", *ptr);

    /* perform bitwise AND for every bit of the character */
    for(i = 7; i >= 0; --i) 
        if(*ptr & 1 << i) 
          str[7-i]='1';
        else
          str[7-i]='0';
        //(*ptr & 1 << i) ? putchar('1') : putchar('0');
    str[8]='\0';    
    printf("%s\n",str);
    memset(str,'/0',8);        
}
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
H => 01001000
e => 01100101
l => 01101100
l => 01101100
o => 01101111
Abort trap
```

It would be nice if someone can throw some light. Even though i am getting the output, the trap is happening.

Courtesy: This is a modified program of a fellow stack fellow user @Athabaska.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str[8]='\0'` causes a buffer overflow because `str` only has 8 elements, and you're trying to access the ninth one.

Edit: I complained about the `'/0'`, but as @R.. informed me, it *is* valid - however, `memset()` will ultimately convert its parameter to `unsigned char`, so I don't think there is any point in using it, so I assume the author will want to change it to `'\0'`.

Comment: `'/0'` is valid C. It's a multi-character constant which has implementation-defined value, usually defined as interpreting the bytes in that order as a native-endian number.

Comment: @R..: +1; I didn't know that. Don't see the point of passing a multi-character value to a function that will ultimately convert its parameter to 'unsigned char', though...

Comment: Well on typical implementations, it would fill with either `'/'` or `'0'` depending on the system's endianness. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`str[8]='\0';` is invalid. If declaration is `char str[8];` then valid indices are `0..7`

Answer (score 2):

str[] only has space for 8 characters, but you access the 9th: `str[8] = '\0';`